# I need to display a pop up table on clicking a button in vb.net. How do i do this without the gridviews just on plain button click?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need a table to pop up or flash on the users screen when a button is clicked
It is a reference table, users can go back and check the codes while filling a form. This is to be done vb.net. Please help me i need the simplest solution possible

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it's to broad to answer. Please update your question with what you have tried and where you are having issues. Asking `This is to be done vb.net. Please help me i need the simplest solution possible` is off topic as we are not a coding site and you will not get much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my opinion:

1) If you don't insist on formatting and you would like to only display table data, you can simply write the data into string, which you will display in a MsgBox dialog. You'll probably will have to take care about partial string lenghts in columns (trim, or complete with spaces to a specific length) and then it will look OK. Bellow is an example of such data (only a test dialog) without any trimming/completeng:

[image: table MsgBox dialog example]

2) For a serious table, you'd have to either use datagrdiveiw (or such) in a separate form, or draw your table using GDI, which would be a rather complicated and eccentric method.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question answered, if you consider the issue resolved.